# Open fire creating a room issue

Tags: macos, xmpp, openfire

I am using open fire for creating jabber server but when i create a chat room it is
showing the following exception

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal JID: chat1@conference.202.56.215.54@conference.201.54.215.54
    at org.xmpp.packet.JID.(JID.java:554)
    at org.xmpp.packet.JID.(JID.java:508)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.muc_002droom_002dedit_002dform_jsp._jspService(muc_002droom_002dedit_002dform_jsp.java:90)...
```

please help me with this

Comment: Excatly what i am facing too! can you please help me what should i do next? i can not proceed further on group chat tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is an illegal JID.  I don't know how you are creating the room, but it looks like you are specifying a full JID as the name when only the room name is required.

Thus when the service domain is added to the supplied name to produce a full JID, you now have an invalid name (@service.name is duplicated).

Comment: Agreed its invalid JID i am having issue like 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal JID: test !!@conference.host
this is invalid JID but what should i have to do to prevent from this ?can you please help ?